# Ubuntu Server auto download torrents

Tags: server, bittorrent

I am looking for a torrent program that i will download torrents place in a certain folder. I have a similar program for NZBs called hellanzb.

I would like the best recommended software for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think [rTorrent](http://libtorrent.rakshasa.no/) will do what you want. I've not used it personally but I know people who use it in a setup in a similar way.

Comment: http://kmandla.wordpress.com/2007/05/02/howto-use-rtorrent-like-a-pro/ (Search for ` Watch a directory`)

Answer (score 3):

[Transmission](http://www.transmissionbt.com/) can be configured to watch a directory for torrent files, and has cli / gui / web frontends you can use to control and configure it.